# Can I travel to holland from Greece with a refugee travel document if my residence permit is still pending?

Tags: greece, refugees

I want to travel to Holland from Greece without a Greek residence permit as it is still pending. Can we instead travel with passports of refugees in Greece?

Comment: What exactly is the image you show?

Comment: What image mdewey ?

Comment: @Embaye the image that you removed. Sadly for you - it's still visible in the edit history of the question. So please don't act like this.

Comment: Am so sorry it does not mean any thing , i was unconcious while i was posting a question.

Comment: Unclear, eg "unconcious while i was posting". Putting on hold until clarified.